# Is there a method, using Firestorage, to transform a collection into a List of maps, without Streambuilder/widget?

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

Is there a method, using Firestorage, to transform a collection into a List of maps, without Streambuilder/widget?

Example: I have a collection "exampleData" which has documents. I need to create a "List of Maps" from it, using the collection's data. Example of data:

```
List<Map> exampleData = [map1,map2,map3]
```

The elements in that list have data like this:

```
map1 = {
"active":"true"
"age" = "2"
"editing" = "false"
"photo_url" = "https://test.com"
"score: 0"
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? The question is not understandable and a bit too broad for my taste.

Comment: That's still unclear. What do you mean by transform ? What's the expected result ?

Comment: @RémiRousselet Transforming the `List<DocumentSnapshot` into a `List<Map>`, where the `Map` will contain the *`data`* of **`DocumentSnapshot`**'s from the original `List`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you have a variable called `listOfMaps`, which is of type `List<Map>`.

```
List<Map> listOfMaps;
```

You could supply that object with realtime updates of your collection like this:

```
final Stream<List<Map>> mappedStream = collectionReference.snapshots().map((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  // returning a Map that contains all values marked in your screenshot
  return snapshot.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) => document.data);
});

// assigning the data to the listOfMaps by listening to the Stream
mappedStream.listen((List<Map> data) => listOfMaps = data);
```

We can use the `snapshots()` *`Stream<List<QuerySnapshot>>`* to get a `Stream` containing **all** *documents* as *objects (`DocumentSnapshot`)*. For that, we can use the `map` function to convert the `List<QuerySnapshot>` to a `List<Map`.

The [`data` property](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_snapshot.dart#L22) of each `DocumentSnapshot` in the `List<DocumentSnapshot>` holds a **`List<Map>`** with *every field from your database*.

```
// alternatively the Stream can be used e.g. in a StreamBuilder
StreamBuilder(
  stream: mappedStream,
  builder: ...
);
```

To summarize:

- *Before* the conversion, we can get a *`List<DocumentSnapshot>`* from the `snapshots()` *`Stream`*
- *Afterwards*, we have converted that into a *`List<Map>`* by using the `data` property of the *`DocumentSnapshots`'s*
- The ***`mappedStream`*** can either be listened on to e.g. assign the data to an object in our application or used in something like a [`StreamBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)

Comment: calling `map` on the stream directly instead of doing it inside `listen` would be better

Comment: I think that in this example it is rather *negligible* because one would have to attach a `listen` after the mapping again, but I will change it anyway because the resulting `Stream` could also be used in a *`StreamBuilder`*.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Anyway, I do not know a way of not mapping inside the callback, even when mapping the `Stream` more beautifully.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Thanks a lot, this is an exact answer and explanation that I needed

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Nah it's fine. You can't do much better here, that's the proper way to use streams. Much better this way ! :D